# Spring Security, Azure AD and logout functionality - is it possible to logout without redirection that leads to 404?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I am battling against Spring Security logout. I have to mention that I am not the sharpest tool in the shed when it comes to Spring Security, and especially combined with Azure AD.

I have a `SecurityFilterChain` configuration looking like this:

```
@Bean
fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .httpBasic()
        .disable()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
        .logoutRequestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer { oauth2Configurer: OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity?> ->
            oauth2Configurer.jwt()
        }.authorizeRequests { auth ->
            auth.antMatchers(
                "/actuator/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**",
            )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        }.oauth2Client()
    return http.build()
}
```

I am specifically talking about this part:

```
 .and()
 .logout()
 .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
 .logoutRequestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
 .clearAuthentication(true)
```

When I shot a `POST /logout` to the controller, I get a `404` response and an exception caught by a `@ExceptionHandler`:

```
{
    "requestUri": "/login",
    "status": 404,
    "statusText": "Not Found",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-30T18:23:45.59681+03:00",
    "errorMessage": "No handler found for GET /login"
}
```

and a bit of the stacktrace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path
> resource
> [fi/vr/fleetcare/varpubff/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]:
> Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception
> is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with
> '/' or with 'http(s)'

As I am not using Spring WebMvc (at least directly) but the software I'm developing is just a Backend-For-Frontend for an Android application.

So my question is: Is it possible to somehow skip, disable or properly configure that `logoutSuccessUrl`, so the user gets logged out without throwing an exception?

Or is my approach completely wrong and I should do this completely different?

Comment: The `logoutSuccessUrl` has to be an existing endpoint. However, you could also set a custom [`LogoutSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.htm)